# SQL Server isnull is not working with another expression?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to make an expression in SQL Server, that will check if certain column is null, and if it is null, set a new GUID number..

This is my code :

```
select 
    isnull((select Guid 
            from therapists 
            where username = 'ido' and password = 'ido'), 
           (update therapists 
            set guid = NEWID() 
            where username = 'ido' and password = 'ido'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE therapists SET guid = NEWID() 
WHERE username = 'ido' 
  AND password = 'ido'
  AND guid IS NULL;
```